# .slideToggle behaviour different for the image

Tags: jquery, slidetoggle

I started learning JQuery.

Here is my code:

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css"/>
        <script type="text/Javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="my.js"></script>
        <title>My Jquery</title>
    </head>
    <body>

    <div class="parent"><img src="images.jpg" class="pic"/></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**stylesheet.css**

```
.pic
{
    border: 1px solid red;
    visibility: hide;
}
.parent
{
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

**my.js**

```
 $(document).ready(
                    function(){
                        $(".pic").click(
                                function(){
                                                $(this).slideToggle(5000);
                                          }
                                         );
                    });
```

The problem is that `slideToggle` hides the element by sliding horizontally/vertically except for the image I have added. For image ,it slides across the diagonal. Why is the behaviour different to image?

Answer (score 0):

Try calling `.slideToggle()` on `$(this).parent()` within `click` handler

```js
 $(document).ready(
   function() {
     $(".pic").click(
       function() {
         $(this).parent().slideToggle(5000);
       }
     );
   });
```

```css
.pic {
  border: 1px solid red;
  visibility: hide;
}
.parent {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div class="parent">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/nature" class="pic" />
</div>
```

Comment: Currently I am doing it on the parent. But why doesn't it work on image, that is my doubt.

Comment: @InQusitive `.slideToggle()` does apply effect to image . Try viewing `.pic` at Elements at `console` during animation . Does applying `.slideToggle()` to parent element return expected result ?

Comment: @InQusitive _"Yes applying to parent element works fine."_ Is Question resolved ?

Comment: @InQusitive _"Resolved by setting width of image."_ If none of the solutions provided resolve Question , can post , accept solution that resolved Question ?

Answer (score 0):

I finally resolved the issue. This was done by setting the width of the image

```
.pic
{
    border: 1px solid red;
    display: block;
    width: 300px; //added this line

}
```

Now it works fine.